# What type of graph is this. I shows kind of cause and effect.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, math-software

I am trying to create a chart like this that shows item 1 effects items 2 and 4 type chart. I didn't really know where to post this so I thought mathematics would be the right place because of the amount of charts and graphs we deal with. If anyone could tell me the name of this type of chart I would appreciate it. Extra Kudos if you could tell me a program I can quickly create one in. I have to do this for over 20 items.

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Mathematically, that should be redrawn as a directed graph.  But I don't think that you are actually looking for a mathematical answer.

Comment: I see what your saying. I might be able to work with that though having over 20 items might look kind of crazy. I really thought that graph/chart had a specific name. I knew I saw this other places just don't know where...

Comment: Mathematically, it seems that you'd like to create a (directed) [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).  That is, you're making a web in which no two items on the same side are connected.

Comment: "That is, you're making a web in which no two items on the same side are connected" Everything looked perfect then I saw that part. The chart I am trying to do would be a bipartite graph but the problem is I want to compare the same list against it self. So instead of like the picture in that wiki example that shows a purple list and a green list I would want to take the green list and link it together with the items it effects. @__@ wow my head just spun.

Comment: Ah, so we wouldn't have it broken down into two lists. My understanding then is we would just have however many items in the list (or a dot for each item, I guess), and an arrow between any two items representing some kind of relationship. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. So we make a list of say 5 items. We then mirror that list as seen in the image. 1-6 and another list 1-6 (they are the same list , same items, same order). The lines show relation. So starting from the top left. 1 will effect 2 and 3. 2 will effect 1 and 4. We also see that 4 and 5 has no effects and 6 just effects itself. 

If this helps I am trying to accomplish a visual chart to show when one items changes it will need to update certain other items in a list, or perhaps just update itself, or update nothing. Did that make any sense? I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: So I'm not sure I understand what's going on here. To show that using 6 updates 6, do you want an arrow going from the left 6 to the right 6, or do you want an arrow starting from the 6 and pointing that goes in a loop and points back at that 6?

Comment: I don't know anything about graph theory, but I think what you're looking for is a visual representation of a directed graph as the quotient of a bipartite graph.

Comment: I would rather make a graph that looks similar to the one above so two list of the same items. Arrow coming out of the 6 circle pointing to the 6 in the other list, instead of looping and pointing to itself. 

The loop way sounds like thats what it would look like with just one list but the way I am wanting to show is with two.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the picture you've drawn is essentially a bipartite graph, if you relabel the vertices on the right $1',2',\ldots$. Now there's probably a way to take a "quotient" be an equivalence relation $\{(1,1'),\ldots\}$ to get the directed graph you are really after.

Comment: Right. So what you're looking for in the end of the day **is** a bipartite graph because all arrows go from something on the left to something on the right.  In other words, no arrows connect a left-thing to a left-thing or a right-thing to a right-thing.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yea I guess so. Seems like it.

Comment: Now that that's settled, we have to figure out how to do something like this at a reasonable speed. You could do this with mathematical programming software [like mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15112/how-to-generate-and-draw-simple-bipartite-graphs) or Sage, but I wouldn't buy something like that for only this purpose. You might want to try asking this question on the [graphic design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, never underestimate the power of Microsoft Paint (or [Paintbrush](https://www.google.com/search?q=paintbrush+mac&oq=paintbrush+mac&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3058j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=13d6aa3a7d487f41&q=download+paintbrush+mac), if you're a Mac guy)